# How to connect to Wifi via WPS-PBC from win cmd

Tags: windows, wireless-networking, cmd.exe, wps

Have any ways to connect to wireless network by **WPS PBC** (push button) from **command line** in **Windows** OS?

May be needed add special profile in **netsh**?

Comment: Please explain more about what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: I want: 1. push button on router 2. Run script on windows PC -> and then PC will connect to router

Answer (score 0):

You may use the `netsh` command for that.

Here is how :

- Start CMD
- Run the command `netsh wlan show profile` to view all the
  available network profiles and find the matching one for your router
- To connect use this command :

  ```
  netsh wlan connect ssid=YOUR-WIFI-SSID name=PROFILE-NAME
  ```
- If your computer has more than one WiFi adapter,
  you also need to specify the adapter name using the command:

  ```
  netsh wlan connect ssid=YOUR-WIFI-SSID name=PROFILE-NAME interface=Wi-Fi-interface
  ```

Note that in the future you only need the `netsh` command in order
to connect (you don't need again to list the profiles).

Comment: If I had a profile, I wouldn't need wps,right?   At that moment i don`t have profile for that router/ssid. May be neede create new profile, bit i don`t know which settings must be. I can`t find information in docs about creating new profiles for wps connect

Comment: You will need to connect once manually in order to establish the profile.

Comment: Unfortunately, the goal is to check the correctness of the WPS operation of access points on Windows systems automatically. If there is a profile (manual connection ...etc) - WPS does not participate in the process